# iOS push notifications: what is `ThunderingHerdPolicy`?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know what `ThunderingHerdPolicy` on iOS is? I have read [Thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem), which helps me roughly guess what domain this problem is in, but I still have no real understanding. There should **not** be many processes contending for this push notification I sent, so `ThunderingHerdPolicy` is not the conventional "thundering herd problem". Another interesting term in the log message was `timeSinceThunderingHerdTriggerEvent`. What's that.

When looking in `Console.app`, I found a log message printed when my push notification message was ignored/ throttled and not shown to the device/ user.

The log message shows:

```sh
{name: ThunderingHerdPolicy, policyWeight: 1.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceInUse == 1 AND timeSinceThunderingHerdTriggerEvent < 900}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
```

If I were to guess, iOS had detected a thundering herd event where many apps were competing for network or battery resource. However, `timeSinceThunderingHerdTriggerEvent` was exactly 900 (probably in seconds, or 15 minutes) which means the event was triggered immediately when the push notification was received. Maybe there was too much background work by my app or other apps recently, or a bug.

Comment: Could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525437/341994

Comment: Interesting, `timeSinceThunderingHerdTriggerEvent` was only `300` (probably seconds/ 5 minutes) on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525437/341994. Thanks, there's some nice investigation in the same area, in that answer. However, in 2018 someone found it to be `900` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879117/7365866

Comment: I've just asked this on the Apple developer forums too: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689582